# Не могу настроить intent-filter activity, чтоб при открытии файла в FileManager мое acticity появлялся в диалоге предложенных app

Tags: java, android

Использую следующий код:

```
<activity
        android:name=".FileManager"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.mp3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.mp3" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Но в списке предложенных появляется только стандартный плеер. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: пробовали `<data android:pathPattern="*.mp3" />`?

Comment: @metalurgus пробовал, безрезультатно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема оказалось в эмуляторе genymotion. Если установить на телефон, то все работает.